# How to transfer funds from Bitstamp to a personal wallet?

Tags: withdrawal, bitstamp, europe

I converted EURs into BTCs at Bitstamp.net with SEPA (I live in the in EU), so now the BTCs are sitting on my Bitstamp account, but what's the next step? How do I use and send these BTCs to an average 34 digit bitcoin address?

Could anyone write or explain step by step in nutshell what do I have to do, what other websites or programs do I have to use to transfer my bitcoins from Bitstamp to a 34 digit bitcoin address?

What are the possible ways of doing it?

Comment: TL;DR: my suggestion is to create a wallet at https://blockchain.info/wallet/

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking what option lets you withdraw from BitSTAMP?

Across the top menu is Withdraw, and from there pick Bitcoin as the withdrawal method, which gives this link:

- https://www.bitstamp.net/account/withdraw/bitcoin/

Now if you are asking where to withdraw your coins to, then that's a different question.  There is not just one answer because various options regarding security will determine the best way to proceed.

If you are looking to store them for a long time, then a paper wallet, generated from an offline computer using a LiveOS might be the right recommendation.

Armory is another client that can be used offline and be very secure for storing bitcoins.

Or perhaps storing the funds using a hyrbrid EWallet, like the one from Blockchain.info/wallet is a good method because it provides a good tradeoff between convenience and security.

Others feel their coins are safe in a hosted (shared) EWallet provider like Coinbase, Paytunia or prefer to leave funds at an exchange even.  If the exchange has two-factor authentication (done properly) that will help prevent the situation where even if your computer is compromised you EWallet account is not at risk of a replay attack.

Others want to run a full Bitcoin.org client themselves.  This is an undertaking as initial startup can take a day or longer to download the blockchain.  A future release of the Bitcoin.org client will make this initial and ongoing performance issue be much less of a burden.  Other clients, Simplified Payment Verification (SPV) clients, such as Multibit.

- http://bitcoinmagazine.net/bitcoin-wallet-options
- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mobile_Payment_Apps